# How zsh interprets $HOME:abc

Tags: zsh

Why does zsh interpret $HOME:abc like /userbc? bash interprets it as /user:abc.

```bash
zsh
$echo $HOME:abc
/userbc

bash
$echo $HOME:abc
/user:abc
```

Comment: The `:abc` does make sense in zsh, because `b` and `c` are not valid modifiers. That's why zsh interprets only the `a` modifier, and you get the same result as if you would just write `$HOME:a`. In bash, you don't have such modifiers at all, and that's why you get just `$HOME` expanded.

Answer (score 2):

History expansion, filename generation and parameter expansion all have [modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) of the form `:N` after the expansion. `:a` means to expand to an absolute path. Use `${HOME}:abc` instead to treat the colon as a literal character.

Comment: This parameter substitution seems to come from [csh-style](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_12.html#:~:text=Also%2C%20csh%2Dstyle%20%3A%20modifiers%20may%20be%20appended%20to%20a%20parameter%20substitution)

Answer (score 1):

You are using zsh modifiers, of which “a” is a valid one.

```
echo ${HOME}:abc
/root:abc
```

Avoid in zsh by using {}.